# Changing element from span to input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the type of a span field to an input field on select. Currently I have found code that changes the element when the element itself is clicked, but I am trying to figure out a way to change that element when another is clicked.

here is the current fiddle I am in: http://jsfiddle.net/2D9FW/281/

```
<span class="loadNum">5566</span><a class="editrow" style="display: 
float-left"data-value="">  clickme</a>
<br />
<span class="loadNum">5566</span><a class="editrow" style="display: 
float-left"data-value=""> clickme</a>



    var switchToInput = function () {
    var $input = $("<input>", {
        val: $(this).text(),
        type: "text"
    });
    $input.addClass("loadNum");
    $(this).replaceWith($input);
    $input.on("blur", switchToSpan);
    $input.select();
};
var switchToSpan = function () {
    var $span = $("<span>", {
        text: $(this).val()
    });
    $span.addClass("loadNum");
    $(this).replaceWith($span);
    $span.on("click", switchToInput);
}
$(".loadNum").on("click", switchToInput);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of Jquery [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to achieve what you are looking for

Try this

```
var switchToInput = function () {
    var $input = $("<input>", {
        val: $(this).prev('.loadNum').text(),
        type: "text"
    });
    $input.addClass("loadNum");
    $(this).prev('.loadNum').replaceWith($input);
    $input.on("blur", switchToSpan);
    $input.select();
};
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2D9FW/282/)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying something similar but forgot to include it on the replace